# Magento2 character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'

Tags: magento2, product, error

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'handle': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 1

I get this error when I go to the producturl.
http://muy.test:8065/en_de/test-product.html

Comment: did you find any solution to this?